# Accidently ran `sudo chown root@root -R /.` instead of `sudo chown root@root -R ./`

Tags: linux, sudo, undo, chown

I wanted to change tho permission of a file structure and accidently ran

`sudo chown root@root -R /.`

instead of

`sudo chown root@root -R ./`

is there anyway i can undo that?
I don't have a backup of my system. If there is nothing a can do I'll just install a different os since all the relevant data is backed up.

Comment: There is nothing you can do. Reinstall. What was `.` when you ran the command? It does not make any difference for the outcome, I am just wondering why would someone change the owner of all the files in a directory to `root`.

Comment: Had some modules missing in the amdgpu folder and wanted to changed ownership from my main user to root so they would be accessable. Then I messed up the order of ./ and now I'm just glad that my browser still works so I can still get through the school day and install endeavour os later at home, which i've been putting off for quite some time now. Well guess I have a reason to do it now.

Comment: In the future you can avoid this by only using `.` – there's no benefit in writing `./`, only increased chance for mistakes

Comment: I should probably also just use the entire path instead of going into that dir first. Even less chance  for error.

Comment: The files in your home directory should be owned by you. Similar for the home directories of the other users, if there are any. You can fix that easily.

Comment: Most of the files outside the home directories are owned by `root` anyway but not all of them and some system applications do not work if their configuration files are owned by `root` either because they cannot read or write those files in this new setup or because they are programmed to not work when their files do not have the right owner/group and permissions (this is mostly for security). Your system may keep working well but some things (like the email server, if you have one installed) or the printing or other system services might suddenly throw errors and stop working.

Comment: I can still use the webbrowser which is all I need for now, but yeah everything else is owned by `root`, even the home dirs. So yeah nothing will start and i can't change the ownership of any files now. So I'll just have to reinstall a OS.